# How do I implement a filter through an instance?

Tags: haskell

Is there any instance to use a filter with its own type? Right now I have this type:

```
data Tree a = Leaf | Node a Color (Tree a) (Tree a) deriving (Show)
```

And I'd like to write something like:

```
filter (>4) tree
```

If there is such an instance, can someone give me an example code, because I do not understand how it should be different from fmap

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In `base`, there's no typeclass for `filter` and it can only be used on lists. But if you use [the `witherable` package](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/witherable-0.4.2), then you'll get a `Filterable` typeclass that you can use. Here's the beginning of one possible instance for your type:

```
instance Filterable Tree where
    mapMaybe _ Leaf = Leaf
    mapMaybe f (Node x c l r) = case f x of
        Just j -> _
        Nothing -> _
        where l' = mapMaybe f l
              r' = mapMaybe f r
```

Once you finish writing `mapMaybe`, you'll get `catMaybes` and `filter` for free.

Comment: It's worth noting `Filterable` = `FunctorOf (Kleisli Maybe) []`.

Comment: @Iceland_jack What is `FunctorOf`? On its surface, the claim seems strange, since nothing in `Filterable` mentions `[]`.

Comment: Sorry meant `FunctorOf (Kleisli Maybe) (->)`, https://www.reddit.com/r/haskell/comments/eoo16m/base_category_polymorphic_functor_and_functorof/

Answer (score 3):

Any filter that removes items will involve a lot of rebalancing anyway, for a red-black tree, won't it? So I'm not really sure this can be much more efficient than getting the elements to keep as a list and rebuilding the tree from scratch by insertions. Presuming the obvious `Foldable Tree` instance and a function `insert :: a -> Tree a -> Tree a`, I'd just define

```
filterTree :: (a -> Bool) -> Tree a -> Tree a
filterTree f = foldr insert Leaf . foldMap keep
  where keep n | f n = [n]
               | otherwise = []
```

But of course since it's obviously expensive, I'd try to avoid using it.